# SQL Server Group By in an UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

How is it possible to use `GROUP BY` in this statement?

```
UPDATE LoanMaster 
SET LeadsID1 = NEXT VALUE FOR LM
WHERE PrdAcctId IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY LBrCode, CustNo
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to speculate that you want a unique id for the pair `LBrCode` and `CustNo`.  You can do this as:

```
with nums as (
      SELECT t.*, (NEXT VALUE FOR LM) as newval
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT LBrCode, CustNo
            FROM LoanMaster
            WHERE PrdAcctId IS NOT NULL
           ) t
     )
update lm
    set LeadsId1 = newval
    from LoanMaster lm JOIN
         nums
         on lm.LBrCode = nums.LBrCode and lm.CustNo = nums.CustNo;
```

Note:  Although this should work, you should really create a `Leads` table with one row per value.  It seems like you want a foreign key relationship, and you should have an entity for that relationship.